# Command output redirect with supervisord

Tags: supervisord

```
docker -H :4000 events | ./docker_events.py
```

`docker -H :4000 events` will gives the events continuously until we press `Crtl+C`. So, I `pipe` the output to my custom script `docker_events.py` which parses the output which was returned by `docker -H :4000 events` and then gives it own version of output (actually it will send json data to `redis`!)

I inclued the above line in `supervisord` `.conf` like below

```
[program:docker_events]
command=docker -H :4000 events | python /root/docker_events.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/docker_events.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/docker_events.out.log
```

but it is not working properly; I can see error in  `docker_events.err.log`

```
Usage:  docker events [OPTIONS]

Get real time events from the server
docker: "events" requires 0 arguments.
See 'docker events --help'.
```

It is taking `|` as argument. So can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the shell piping and it is not handled properly in your config file. My guess a correct command might be

```
command=bash -c "docker -H :4000 events | python /root/docker_events.py"
```